# Downgrading from android 4.0 to Android 2.2 creates lot of problems

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have created Android application with 

that was working very fine on android greater than ICS (4.0), but it does not install's on android 2.2.

I searched and found that change android:minSdkVersion="8" and it will be compatible with Android 2.2. It worked for me and applications installs on 2.2. but now it crashes on first button click.

Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.
[2013-11-15 00:24:56 - Track] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: java.nio.BufferOverflowException. Check the Eclipse log for stack trace.

Comment: Show some code around the problematic area

Comment: What does the button do? Do you have the support library added?

Answer (score 2):

There is most definitely some API call or resource you're using that isnt supported in the sdk version you're downgrading to.

Lint and Clean your eclipse project.  When I change the minimum API version, sometimes eclipse doesnt tell me which API calls have changed/arent available anymore.

Clean your project from the menu: Project → Clean

And to lint:
[image]

If that doesnt work you're going to have to try a different button or check the calls you're using when that button is clicked.